# Hybris setup for multiple projects

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Mostly coming from a java background, I am unable to completely understand how Hybris application is to be developed.

I want to know if a single setup of Hybris (on a developer machine) can be used for multiple projects i.e. lets say a b2b_acc and b2c_acc, can we have both at the same time on the same hybris 6.x platform?

Since all configurations happen in the same `localextensions.xml`, will they not conflict with each other and cause any problems?

Assume that both the b2b and b2c sites are for completely different customers.

Also the database tables that are created.Will these work as expected?

Further how about the backoffice, hmc, hac URLs?

Do these need to be configured on different ports for both these sites?

In eclipse, just as we can have multiple java projects in the same workspace,

Is it possible to work on two completely different Hybris projects (having the same hybris 6.0 setup) in the same workspace?

Lastly, in normal java world, Tomcat does not require different ports for two different applications, i.e. we can deploy multiple apps in tomcat. Is the same possible for two different Hybris projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a system in place for running multiple shops on one hybris instance. 
It's called Tenants.
Search the hybris wiki for "Multi-Tenant Systems" it should give you the details.